# HTML-парсер таблиц с выводом в TXT-файл на JAVA

Tags: java, html, jsoup

Подскажите как сделать HTML-парсер таблиц с выводом в TXT-файл на JAVA.

Вот, что смог сделать сам:

```
public class HTMLParser {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File input = new File("d:/1/example.html");
        org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8");
        String file = doc.html();

        String trLine = file.substring(file.indexOf("<tr>"),file.indexOf("</tr>"));
        int countTd = 2;
        int countTr = 0;
        String[] str = trLine.split(">*<");
        for (String string : str){
            if(string.contains("/td>")){
                countTd++;
            } if(string.contains("colspan")){
                countTd += Integer.parseInt(string.substring(string.indexOf("\"") +1, string.lastIndexOf("\""))) - 1;
            }
        }
        String[] str2 = file.split("<tr>");
        for(String string : str2){
            if(string.contains("</tr>")){
                countTr++;
            }
        }
         countTr = countTr * 2 +1;

        String[][] table = new String[countTr][countTd];
        for (int i  = 0; i < countTr; i++){
            table[i][0] = "*";
            table[i][countTd-1] = "*";
        }



        String[] lines = file.split("\n");
        int y = 1;
        int x = 1;


        for(int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
            if(lines[i].contains("<td>")){
                for(int a = 0; a <countTd; a++ ){
                    if(table[y][x + a] == null ){
                        table[y][x] = lines[i].substring((lines[i].indexOf('>') + 1), lines[i].lastIndexOf("</td>") );
                        x++;
                        a = countTd;
                  }
                }

            } else if(lines[i].contains("colspan")){
                int colspan = Integer.parseInt(lines[i].substring((lines[i].indexOf('\"') + 1),lines[i].lastIndexOf('\"')));
                table[y][x] = lines[i].substring((lines[i].indexOf('>') + 1 ), lines[i].lastIndexOf('<') );
                x+=colspan;
            } else if(lines[i].contains("</tr>")){
                x = 1;
                y++;
            } else if(lines[i].contains("rowspan")){
                int rowspan = Integer.parseInt(lines[i].substring((lines[i].indexOf('\"') + 1),lines[i].lastIndexOf('\"')));
                table[y][x] = lines[i].substring((lines[i].indexOf('>') + 1 ), lines[i].lastIndexOf('<') );
                for(int j = 1; j != rowspan; j++){
                    table[y+j][x] = " ";
                }
                x++;
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i<countTr; i++){
            String s = "";
            for(int j =0; j< countTd; j++){
                s+=table[i][j];
            }
            ConsoleHelper.println(s);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: а что не работает в вашей программе?

Comment: Неверно отображается таблица и проблема со вложенностью.

Answer (score 1):

Вы очень странно решаете задачу. Вы воспользовались Jsoup только для того, чтобы получить ту же строку, кою в него и передали. После чего вытаскиваете данные простыми строковыми методами, тогда как надо было продолжать пользоваться Jsoup-ом.

Вам надо примерно так действовать, доставая элементы HTML кода по именам их тегов:

```
File input = new File("d:/1/example.html");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8");
Elements trs = doc.getElementsByTag("tr");
for(Element tr : trs)
{
    Elements tds = tr.getElementsByTag("td");
    for(Element td : tds )
    {
        String strInTd = td.text();
        System.out.println(strInTd);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, Юрий.

Comment: Но проблема даже не в том, как считать файл, а как его отобразить в текстовом виде с сохранением формата.

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/Iu2Pi64ctJVP9

Comment: @user215185, нема прав на просмотр. И поясните про `"отобразить в текстовом виде с сохранением формата"`

Comment: поправил ссылку

Comment: там полный текст задания.

Comment: Буду рад любым идеям как это реализовать.

Comment: @user215185, сомневаюсь, что такую задачу вам тут кто-то решать станет. А вообще там ничего особо сложного - получаете сначала структуру данных описанным в вопросе способом, а потом пишите алгоритм заполнения текстового файла.

Comment: @user215185, вам надо с такими задачами на фриланс-биржу идти.